# Clarification about Django-Oscar

Tags: django, e-commerce, django-oscar

I have already finished setting up my home, about and contact us page using bootstrap in one project. I wanted to use the django-oscar for the e-commerce configuration and use it in my products page.

Do I need to add another project or just create another app for django-oscar?

By the way I created another project and am currently stuck on how to connect it the first project I have made

Comment: you don't need another project. http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.4/internals/getting_started.html

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another project for your product's page. You can easily install Oscar (which will install Django as a dependency). It supports a simple design built with Twitter's Bootstrap.

You can read this: [Getting started with Oscar](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.4/internals/getting_started.html) and [How to customise templates](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.4/howto/how_to_customise_templates.html) for create home, about and contacts  pages.

Hope I help!

Comment: Yes, you need to override Oscar's default configs and templates: [Documentation](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.4/topics/customisation.html)